# Is it possible to create anti-muons in a particle accelerator?

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter, particle-accelerators, leptons, cherenkov-radiation

I love particle and nuclear physics and I'm starting to search some things about it even. So, my doubt is: is it possible to create antimuons (positive charged muons) in a particle accelerator, but without colliding two beams? I mean, only colliding a beam against objects or with the help of machines like Cherenkov detectors or Muon filters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  In fact, the first process you generally learn about in quantum field theory is the annhilation of an electron/positron pair to produce a muon/antimuon pair.

Comment: You don't even have to get that exotic. NuSea (AKA fermilab experiment 866) used Drell-Yan muon/antimuon pairs from (among other cases) a proton beam on a stationary hydrogen target.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer, wouldn't that involve colliding an electron with a positron?

Comment: @JoãoTeixeira You can do Jerry's version in fixed target kinematics with a positron beam and ordinary matter.

Comment: @dmckee I don't know if you can also help me with this issue: which device/machine or process should I use to measure the levels of muonium formed?

Answer (score 4):

> is it possible to create antimuons (positive charged muons) in a particle accelerator, but without colliding two beams? I mean, only colliding a beam against objects

Yes, these are the fixed target experiments, various beams interacting with nuclei in the targets.

In this [bubble chamber picture](http://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2002/Bubblech/8kpimu.html) the target is the protons in the nucleus of the hydrogen atoms:

[image: k-p]

> This picture comes from an experiment at CERN in which a beam of 8.2 GeV/c K- particles is fired into the 2 metre hydrogen-filled bubble chamber.
>
> The main interaction produces 4 charged particles and a neutral particle that decays a little way downstream into two charged charged particles (with a characteristc `vee' shape).
>
> This event is rich in the number of different particles that can be identified from a `reading' of the tracks: electron, positron, pi+, pi-, K0, , K-, mu +, mu-; for details.
> In addition, one can infer the existence of various neutrinos in the decay of the pi+ (muon neutrino) and the mu+ (electron neutrino and antimuon neutrino).

The muons, + and - come from decays.

> or with the help of machines like Cherenkov detectors or Muon filters.

There is some confusion here, [detectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/detect.html) *detect particles*, they do *not produce them.* In the picture above the detector is the camera taking the picture, plus the volume of hydrogen where the particles leave a track. The production happens at the vertices. In particular the muon producing  vertices is where the green tracks begin, the decay of the Kaon and pion.

[The site may interest you.](http://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2002/Bubblech/)